# Undetermined string or character constant in C

Tags: c, string, character, constants

I am doing a program for class. I keep getting an error and I can't see where the heck I am going wrong. Prof said to look at the example in the book. So I do, and mine looks no different. So I try and type out the one in the book and get the same error in the same spot.  Where am I going wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nmgrades, i, grade;
    int totgrade = 0;
    float average

    printf("First enter the number of grades to process: ");
    scanf("%i", &nmgrades);

    for (i = 1; i <= nmgrades; ++i) {
        printf(enter grade i%: ", i);
        scanf("%i", %grade);

        totgrade = totgrade + grade;

    }

    average = (float) totgrade / nmgrades;

    printf("Grade average %.2f", average);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: missing `;` after float average. `scanf("%i", %grade);` should be `&grade`.

Comment: What compiler are you using that does not warn about `scanf("%i", %grade);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nmgrades, i, grade;
    int totgrade = 0;
    float average; // Forgot semicolon

    printf("First enter the number of grades to process: ");
    scanf("%i", &nmgrades);

    for (i = 1; i <= nmgrades; ++i) {
        //printf(enter grade i%: ", i); // wrong
            printf("enter grade %i: ", i);
        //scanf("%i", %grade);
        scanf("%i", &grade); // Ampersand, not percent


        totgrade = totgrade + grade;

    }

    average = (float)totgrade / nmgrades;

    printf("Grade average %.2f", average);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: OMG, I have been staring at this for 2 hours, thank you. I feel foolish lol